# How to get Scala on Visual Studio Code using Ensime Extension?

Tags: java, scala, visual-studio

I have been able to successfully download Java on my computer. Now how do I get Scala on Visual Studio Code? I heard many people use the Ensime extension in order to get Scala on VS Code. But, there isn't much information online on how I can get Scala working on VS Code using Ensime. Does anyone know how to get Scala on VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the tooling story is a bit sad in scala at the moment.

1) Ensime is no longer maintained (I think it's possible to get VS Code to work with it but its for sure not the primary editor). I still personally use it quite heavily in combination with emacs (which is the primary text editor). There is an official site on Ensime/VSCode but I don't know if it helps much http://ensime.github.io/editors/vscode/

2) Metals is probably your best bet on VSCode but it's still very early in development

3) ScalaIDE is Eclipse with scala flavour

4) IntelliJ with Scala Plugin is probably the easiest to get up and running and I'd guess the most widely used one.

Comment: How do I use Ensime to install Scala on VS Code?

Comment: https://github.com/dragos/dragos-vscode-scala probably like this. but I don't know more really. VSCode&Ensime is pretty sparse